# Can't define instance variable inside "with" scope using PyCharm 2017.1

Tags: pycharm

I use PyCharm to build my **TensorFlow** models. After I upgrade my PyCharm from 2016.3 to 2017.1 the problem comes:

I used to define the instance variable inside a **TensorFlow** `variable_scope` using the `with` python keyword as below:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.var_1

        with tf.variable_scope('some_scope'):
            self.var_2 = tf.get_variable('some_name', ...)
```

When using PyCharm 2016.3, everything works just fine. But in PyCharm 2017.1, when I try to use `self.var_2` in the rest of the code, PyCharm shows a warning:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'var_2' for class 'SomeClass'

Also, autocompletion does not work with `var_2` and `var_2` does not show up as an instance variable of class `SomeClass` in the **Structure** tab where `var_1` does.

Is this a bug of PyCharm 2017.1?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23164) for this bug in our tracker. It is going to be fixed in 2017.1.1.